# Delete table data in MySQL when click button dosen't work

Tags: php, mysql

The data isn't being deleted from a table when user clicks on a button.

I have 2 buttons one of them to delete the data in mysql tabel which called data when I pressed the button. The data still in the table although other queries do work fine.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$arr=array();
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
 $x=$_POST['x']."<br/>";
 $y=$_POST['y']."<br/>";
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
    die('could not connect').mysql_errno();
}
else
{
 mysql_select_db("kmean",$con);
 $sql="INSERT INTO data (x, y)
VALUES
 ('$x','$y')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT x,y FROM data");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  //echo $row['x'] . " " . $row['y']."<br/>";

 array_push($arr,array($row['x'],$row['y']));
  //print_r($r);
  echo "<br />";
  }

  if(isset($_POST['delete']))
  {
    mysql_select_db("kmean", $con);

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM data ");

  }

}
//print_r($arr)."<br>";
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: #1, people need to stop use the mysql_* functions, people end up with too many security problems with.  #2, hopefully this is testing code, selecting the same database over and over again is really not necessary.  #3, you are checking if the delete variable is set, not that its true or 1, is this correct?

Comment: it's testing code not actual code that i would upload to webhost
delete  is name of button

Answer (score 1):

Put `}` before `if(isset($_POST['delete']))` and remove `}` before `//print_r($arr)."<br>";`

Actually, your code is missing one more `}`, so its possible that you'll need to put `}}` before that "if" line.

And try to format code better next time, please :)

**UPDATE**:

```
<?php
$arr=array();
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $x=$_POST['x']."<br/>";
    $y=$_POST['y']."<br/>";
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$con)
    {
        die('could not connect').mysql_errno();
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_select_db("kmean",$con);
        $sql="INSERT INTO data (x, y) VALUES ('$x','$y')";
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT x,y FROM data");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            //echo $row['x'] . " " . $row['y']."<br/>";

            array_push($arr,array($row['x'],$row['y']));
            //print_r($r);
            echo "<br />";
        }

    }
    //print_r($arr)."<br>";
    mysql_close($con);
}

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    mysql_select_db("kmean", $con);

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM data ");
}
```

Comment: not working my php designer indicate that the syntax if correct and no missing or increased {}

Comment: Even simple search will show you that there are 6 "{" and 5 "}". I have updated my answer with the correct code for you to use.

Comment: there is no mistake in {} as i have 6{   and 6 } the last } is before 
 end tag of php  ?> so the problem is in query i think

Comment: Then you haven't pasted the whole code. Try the one I posted though. Problem is not in the query its in the position of the "if(isset($_POST['delete']))".

Comment: i'm sorry for not posting the whole code my mistake wher should be the postion of if(isset($_POST['delete']))

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  $arr=array();

  if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

    $x=$_POST['x']."<br/>";
    $y=$_POST['y']."<br/>";

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    if(!$con) die('could not connect').mysql_errno();
    else {
      mysql_select_db("kmean",$con);

      $sql="INSERT INTO data (x, y)
            VALUES
            ('$x','$y')";

      if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

      $result = mysql_query("SELECT x,y FROM data");

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        array_push($arr,array($row['x'],$row['y']));
        echo "<br />";

      }

      if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM data ");
      }
  }

  mysql_close($con);
```